# Split the CGPoint numbers in two CGFloat

Tags: swift, uiimage, cgrect, cgpoint, cgrectmake

Hey guys I have a UIImage that should move to a position which the CGPoint tells.

My code:

```
person1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(corX, corY, 25, 25))
```

What I want to do is to split the CGPoint in two numbers which initialise corX and corY.
Hopefully you can help me.

-Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGPoint` has properties `x` and `y`:

```
person1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 25, 25))
```

Alternatively create the `CGRect` directly from your point as the `origin`
and a given `size`:

```
person1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)))
```

Comment: That makes it much easier. I was looking how I can convert the CGPoint in a String and than find the , in the String to separate the two points.

Comment: @LukasKöhl: You are welcome. (The string description of a variable should only be used for output, but never for further computation.)